# <mvc:view-controller> works in tomcat 6 and jetty, but not tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc

the welcome page doesnt display while deployed in tomcat 7 , why?

Comment: I would look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624568/servlet-as-welcome-file-list-in-tomcat-7. The servlet spec changed slightly regarding welcome files and Tomcat 7 has been updated to handle it whereas Tomcat 6 and Jetty haven't.

Answer (score 1):

it doesnt work on tomcat 7.0.4,after upgraded to tomcat 7.0.11, it works!